# Upper case first letter of each word in a phrase

Tags: python

Ok, I'm trying to figure out how to make a inputed phrase such as this in python ....

```
Self contained underwater breathing apparatus
```

output this...

```
SCUBA
```

Which would be the first letter of each word. Is this something to do with index? and maybe a .upper function?

Comment: you probably have to tokenize the words instead of using split() if your input are more complicated i.e 'Self-contained ...'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the quickest way to get it done

```
input = "Self contained underwater breathing apparatus"
output = ""
for i in input.upper().split():
    output += i[0]
```

Comment: Or as a list comprehension: `first_letters = [ i[0].upper() for i in input.split() ]; output = "".join(first_letters)`

Comment: Works but inefficient, constructs a new string instance in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: do you have to import anything for the .upper? Because I slightly edited your code and it seems that I got an error based off the .upper, Also what exactly does the .split do?

Comment: .split() returns a list of strings delimited by whitespace. What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 25):

This is the pythonic way to do it:

```
output = "".join(item[0].upper() for item in input.split())
# SCUBA
```

There you go. Short and easy to understand.

**LE**:
If you have other delimiters than space, you can split by words, like this:

```
import re
input = "self-contained underwater breathing apparatus"
output = "".join(item[0].upper() for item in re.findall("\w+", input))
# SCUBA
```

Comment: Yep, the join and generator expression is definitely the "right" way. Though it'd be slightly more efficient calling `.upper()` on the entire output, rather than each character.

Answer (score 5):

```
#here is my trial, brief and potent!
str = 'Self contained underwater breathing apparatus'
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y[0].upper(),str.split(),'')
#=> SCUBA
```

Comment: `reduce` for folding strings? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: it works! anyway, probably am bitten badly by a haskell insect :-)

Answer (score 4):

**Pythonic Idioms**

- Using a generator expression over str.split()
- Optimize the inner loop by moving upper() to one call at outside of the loop.

**Implementation:**

```
input = 'Self contained underwater breathing apparatus'
output = ''.join(word[0] for word in input.split()).upper()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
input = 'Self contained underwater breathing apparatus'

output = ''.join(item[0].capitalize() for item in input.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def myfunction(string):
    return (''.join(map(str, [s[0] for s in string.upper().split()])))

myfunction("Self contained underwater breathing apparatus")
```

Returns `SCUBA`

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "Self contained underwater breathing apparatus" 
for item in s.split():
    print item[0].upper()
```

Comment: This is actually wrong, because it will output
`S\n
C\n
U\n
B\n
A\n`

Answer (score 0):

Some list comprehension love:

```
 "".join([word[0].upper() for word in sentence.split()])
```

Comment: Why the unnecessary string format? Why not just `word[0].upper()`?

Comment: oops that was a relic of something else i was trying out.

Answer (score 0):

Another way which may be more easy for total beginners to apprehend:

```
acronym = input('Please give what names you want acronymized: ')
acro = acronym.split() #acro is now a list of each word
for word in acro:
    print(word[0].upper(),end='') #prints out the acronym, end='' is for obstructing capitalized word to be stacked one below the other
print() #gives a line between answer and next command line's return
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get it done this way as well.

```
def get_first_letters(s):
    return ''.join(map(lambda x:x[0].upper(),s.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why no one is using regex? In JavaScript, I would use regex so I don't need to use the loop, please find Python example below.

```
import re
input = "Self-contained underwater & breathing apparatus google.com"
output = ''.join(re.findall(r"\b(\w)", input.upper()))
print(output)
# SCUBAGC
```

Please note that the above regex `/\b(\w)/g` uses \b word boundary and \w word so it will match position between an alphanumeric word character and non-word character so for example “&” is not matched and ".com" “c” is matched and also "s" and "c" is matched on "self-contained"

Alternative Regex using lookahead and lookbehind:

- `/(?!a\s)\b[\w]|&/g` Excluding " a " and including "&"
- `/(?<=\s)[\w&]|^./g` Any word character and "&" after every whitespace. This prevents matching "c" on .com but also prevents matching "c" on "self-contained"

[Code snippet](https://ideone.com/r3WBEH)
[Regex 1](https://regexr.com/5j4vb), [Regex 2](https://regexr.com/5j4ve), [Regex 3](https://regexr.com/5j4vk)