# select first character from each word within a list of scraped data

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Ive been struggling with abbreviating some data scraped using bs4.

I'm trying abbreviate the output from:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/en/2644037/?day1"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")
weekWeather = soup.find('div', {'class':'daily-window'})
wD = [x.text for x in weekWeather.findAll('span', {'class':'description blq-hide'})]
```

The output is a list...

```
['South South Westerly', 'South Westerly', 'Southerly', 'Southerly', 'Southerly']
```

which I want to abbreviate to `['SSW', 'SW', 'S', 'S', 'S']`

My first plan was to use `split()` and then select all `upper()`, then I tried using map to iterate over each word, and select the first character, but I only ever get the first letter back of each element (i.e. `[S, S, S, S, S]`

I have a feeling it's because of the way the data is being returned??

Any pointers would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the first letter of each word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775719/how-do-i-find-the-first-letter-of-each-word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest form, you can *split by space* via `.split()` and get the first character of every word:

```
["".join([item[0] for item in x.text.split()])
 for x in weekWeather.select('span.description.blq-hide')]
```

which would return:

```
['SSW', 'SW', 'S', 'S', 'S']
```