# Comparing abbreviated words in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm experimenting/learning Python with a data set containing information on companies.

The DataFrame structure is the following (these are made up records):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'key': [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999], 
                   'left_name' : ['ET CETERA SYSTEMS', 'ODDS AND ENDS', 'MAXIMA COMPANY', 'MUSIC MANY', 
                                  'GRAPHIC MASTER', 'ARC SECURITY', 'MINDNSOLES', 'REX ENERGY', 'THESIS COMPANY'],
                  'right_name' : ['ET CETERA SYS', 'ODDSNENDS', 'MAX COMP', 'MUSICMANY', 'GRAPHIC MSTR', 
                                  'ARC SECU', 'MIND AND SOLES', 'REXX', 'THESIS COMP']})

print(df)

   key          left_name      right_name
0  111  ET CETERA SYSTEMS   ET CETERA SYS
1  222      ODDS AND ENDS       ODDSNENDS
2  333     MAXIMA COMPANY        MAX COMP
3  444         MUSIC MANY       MUSICMANY
4  555     GRAPHIC MASTER    GRAPHIC MSTR
5  666       ARC SECURITY        ARC SECU
6  777         MINDNSOLES  MIND AND SOLES
7  888         REX ENERGY            REXX
8  999     THESIS COMPANY     THESIS COMP
```

My **goal** is to compare the acronyms of each `(left_name, right_name)` pair. Specifically, if the abbreviated string formed by the concatenation of the initial letters of `left_name` is equal to the abbreviated string formed by the concatenation of the initial letters of `right_name`, then return a flag of `1`. Else, return `0`.

For instance, if we compare the first two abbreviated pairs, then:

- `ECS == ECS` → `1`
- `OAE != O` → `0`

Visually, the resulting DataFrame I'm looking for should look like this:

```
   key          left_name      right_name  name_flag
0  111  ET CETERA SYSTEMS   ET CETERA SYS          1
1  222      ODDS AND ENDS       ODDSNENDS          0
2  333     MAXIMA COMPANY        MAX COMP          1
3  444         MUSIC MANY       MUSICMANY          0
4  555     GRAPHIC MASTER    GRAPHIC MSTR          1
5  666       ARC SECURITY        ARC SECU          1
6  777         MINDNSOLES  MIND AND SOLES          0
7  888         REX ENERGY            REXX          0
8  999     THESIS COMPANY     THESIS COMP          1
```

I think my question is closely related to this one: [Upper case first letter of each word in a phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775719/upper-case-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-phrase)

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to adapt the code appropriately for my problem. Any additional help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def abbr(x):
    return ''.join([letter[0] for letter in x.split(' ')])

df['name_flag'] = (df['left_name'].apply(abbr) == df['right_name'].apply(abbr)).astype(int)
```

output:

```
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    0
7    0
8    1


''.join(re.findall(r'^[A-Z]|\s[A-Z]',s)).replace(' ','')
```

or

```
''.join(re.findall(r'\b\w',s))
```

also works in the function

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job

```
def get_acronym(phrase):
    words = phrase.split(' ')
    return ''.join(w[0] for w in words)

df['name_flag'] = df.right_name.map(get_acronym) == df.left_name.map(get_acronym)
df['name_flag'] = df['name_flag'].astype(int)
```

`df` output

```
   key          left_name      right_name  name_flag
0  111  ET CETERA SYSTEMS   ET CETERA SYS          1
1  222      ODDS AND ENDS       ODDSNENDS          0
2  333     MAXIMA COMPANY        MAX COMP          1
3  444         MUSIC MANY       MUSICMANY          0
4  555     GRAPHIC MASTER    GRAPHIC MSTR          1
5  666       ARC SECURITY        ARC SECU          1
6  777         MINDNSOLES  MIND AND SOLES          0
7  888         REX ENERGY            REXX          0
8  999     THESIS COMPANY     THESIS COMP          1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
l = df.left_name.str.findall(r'\b\w')
r = df.right_name.str.findall(r'\b\w')
df['name_flag'] = (l == r).astype(int)

Out[366]:
   key          left_name      right_name  name_flag
0  111  ET CETERA SYSTEMS   ET CETERA SYS          1
1  222      ODDS AND ENDS       ODDSNENDS          0
2  333     MAXIMA COMPANY        MAX COMP          1
3  444         MUSIC MANY       MUSICMANY          0
4  555     GRAPHIC MASTER    GRAPHIC MSTR          1
5  666       ARC SECURITY        ARC SECU          1
6  777         MINDNSOLES  MIND AND SOLES          0
7  888         REX ENERGY            REXX          0
8  999     THESIS COMPANY     THESIS COMP          1
```

Answer (score 1):

You get get this with

```
df['name_flag'] = df.apply(lambda x:x.left_name.startswith(x.right_name),axis=1).map({True:1,False:0})
```

Comment: Wow!  Very nice solutions, everyone!!